# View data by date after Format 'mmyy'

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I'm trying to answer questions like, how many POs per month do we have? Or, how many lines are there in every PO by month, etc. The original PO dates are all formatted #1/1/2013#. So my first step was to Format each PO record date into 'mmyy' so I could group and COUNT them.

This worked well but, now I cannot view the data by date... For example, I cannot ask 'How many POs after December did we get?' I think this is because SQL does not recognize mm/yy as a comparable date.

Any ideas how I could restructure this?

There are 2 queries I wrote. This is the query to format the dates. This is also the query I was trying to add the date filter to (ex: >#3/14#)

```
SELECT qryALL_PO.POLN, Format([PO CREATE DATE],"mm/yy") AS [Date]
FROM qryALL_PO
GROUP BY qryALL_PO.POLN, Format([PO CREATE DATE],"mm/yy");
```

My group and counting query is:

```
SELECT qryALL_PO.POLN, Sum(qryALL_PO.[LINE QUANTITY]) AS SUM_QTY_PO
FROM qryALL_PO
GROUP BY qryALL_PO.POLN;
```

Comment: Where's the statement that groups the data? Are you trying to *operate against* that result set?

Comment: Also please state the underlying column data type you are using for these date values. Is it a true date/datetime, or a char/varchar used to hold dates. This makes quite a difference.

Comment: The dates are Date/Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format it 'YYYY-MM' , and then use '>' for 'after' clause

Comment: How do you create the WHERE clause? I tried >#2013-12# but Access auto changes it to 12/1/2013

Comment: >"2013-12" or dynamically >format([SomeDate],"yyyy-mm")

Comment: Huh, that first one worked. It's basically treating it like a string, correct?

Comment: absolutely right. and because year is placed before month we can use < and >

Answer (score 1):

You can still count and group dates, as long as you have a way to determine the part of the date you are looking for.

In Access you can use `year` and `month` for example to get the year and month part of the date:

```
select year(mydate)
,      month(mydate)
,      count(*)
from   tableX
group
by     year(mydate)
,      month(mydate)
```

Comment: I will play with this. It's probably the best, most accurate solution. Thank you very much!